# Dragging marker in google maps and changing the coordinates corresponding to it

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markers

If i have two markers on google maps and i reserve the longitude and latitude of the first marker in variables (fromLan, fromLat) and longitude and latitude of the second marker in variables (toLan, toLat). 
I want when dragging one of them to change the longitude and latitude of this marker in order to know whether to change the (fromLan, fromLat) variables or the (toLan, toLat) variables .

Answer (score 2):

add a dragend listener to each marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(fromMarker, 'dragend', function(){
 fromLat = this.getPosition().lat();
 fromLng = this.getPosition().lng();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(toMarker, 'dragend', function(){
 toLat = this.getPosition().lat();
 toLng = this.getPosition().lng();
});
```